# Use Ember store and model as source data for JqGrid

Tags: javascript, ember.js, jqgrid, ember-data

I'd like to use data already populated in my Ember store in a JqGrid.
Any hints on how to achieve this in a better way?

I've found that model objects from the store are not compatible with the array of javascript objects suitable for JqGrid, so I had to create the appropriate array.

This is how I pass the model to the component in a template:

`{{myComponent data=model}}`

And here is how I prepare the jqGrid data:

```
...
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        var myEmberData = this.get('data'); 
        var myJqGridData = myEmberData.map(item => {
            return $.extend({id:item.id},item._internalModel._data);
        }
        ...
        //use myEmberData as local data for JqGrid
        this.$("#gridId").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local", 
            data: myJqGridData,
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this working for you? I've been downing something similar by calling model.toJSON() it's been working fine. Are you making sure to set colModel for jqgrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing 2 private properties it would be better if you'd use `.getProperties()` method and explicitly specify data that you need:

```
const myEmberData  = this.get('data'); 
const myJqGridData = myEmberData.map(
    item => item.getProperties('id', 'firstProperty', 'secondProperty') // ... etc.
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an improvement. Any other idea on how to share the data from the model/store to the JqGrid?

Comment: It looks good. You pass data from route to component and then you use data in component by creating some visual display there. It looks good to me.